# Program loader using native c++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, rpx

I have a dotnet winform application compressed and protected by [RPX Packer](http://rpx.codeplex.com) with a password. The application can be opened from the windows command prompt supplying the password as the command line argument(e.g. MyApp.exe ). Instead of the command prompt I want to start the dotnet app from a native C++ application. I tried the following code which works without a password, but with a password some cryptographic error comes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "shellapi.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;

  shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);

  shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
  shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
  shExecInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
  shExecInfo.lpFile = L"MyApp.exe";
  shExecInfo.lpParameters = L"password";
  shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
  shExecInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
  shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

  ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);

  return 0;
  }
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: "some cryptographic error comes" I guess we'll all take turns and guess what the error is. It might take some time :)

Comment: sure. If I run from command prompt(e.g. MyApp.exe <password>) then the application runs without any problem.

Comment: I always initialize these structures to zero first eg ZeroMemory(&shExecInfo,sizeof(shExecInfo)); before I set the size. Also I use _T("runas") or use SHELLEXECUTEINFOW and not mix Ls with Ts

Comment: @AngusConnell what is the difference between Ls and Ts?

Comment: Ts as TCHARs, Ls as in wide chars strings, if you look into SHELLEXECUTEINFO  you'll find that there is a #define that points to the char * version or the wide char * version. So _T("xx") will be wide char * or char * depending on how you have set up project, it wont change anything, but it means if you change your project setting it will still compile

Comment: Ok, but I am quite perplexed why the app is giving error message. because I can run the dotnet app(MyApp.exe) from the command prompt(e.g. MyApp.exe <password>) by supplying the password as the argument. Bu when the password is given as a parameter from the C++ application the error message is thrown. Why ?

Comment: Yes, it's not the reason why, it was just a stylistic point. Have you tried writing a .NET app that can call "MyApp.exe"? There are other ways to spawn processes in C. But to be honest your way looks fine to me. Sorry not too much help